# Replace column values of one file with values present in another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

Consider two files

file 1:

```
name|gender|phone|email|city|country 
abc|F|11111|ldiskmsjdh|pune|india
xyz|M|22222|wassrrrrtf|delhi|india
```

file2:

```
sno|name|email|country 
1|abc|zzzzzzzz|USA
2|mnq|tttttttt|UK
```

i need the below output needed using unix:

```
name|gender|phone|email|city|country
abc|F|11111|zzzzzzzz|pune|USA
xyz|M|22222|wassrrrrtf|delhi|india
```

NOTE: Match based on primary key i.e “name”

I was able to replace the entire line. But I want to replace only columns for rows when there is match and update only those columns that are present in second file. original format should not change.

I am looking for a general code that will work for N number of columns. Key position shall remain the same.

Comment: First, `bash` and `ksh` are mutually exclusive, you should pick only one of them. Second, neither is a very good choice for this. `awk` is better, but something higher order like `python` or `ruby` would be much easier.

Comment: It will be great if you could help me out with awk command for the same.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I want to print all the records from  file1 irrespective of whether it’s present in file2 or not. If it’s present then we need to update the columns and if it is not..then print the record as it is. As for file2, we do not need to print the records that are not present in file1. Hope that helpful.

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by said code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't normally post an answer when the OP hasn't provided any attempt of their own but since there are multiple answers posted already...

This may be what you want, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR == FNR {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            tags2aFldNrs[$i] = i
        }
    }
    else {
        name = $(tags2aFldNrs["name"])
        names2aVals[name] = $0
    }
    next
}
{
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            tags2bFldNrs[$i] = i
            if ( $i in tags2aFldNrs ) {
                bFldNrs2aFldNrs[i] = tags2aFldNrs[$i]
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        name = $(tags2bFldNrs["name"])
        if ( name in names2aVals ) {
            split(names2aVals[name],aVals)
            for ( bFldNr in bFldNrs2aFldNrs ) {
                aFldNr = bFldNrs2aFldNrs[bFldNr]
                $bFldNr = aVals[aFldNr]
            }
        }
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
name|gender|phone|email|city|country
abc|F|11111|zzzzzzzz|pune|USA
xyz|M|22222|wassrrrrtf|delhi|india
```

That'll work efficiently no matter how many fields you have on each line as it only loops through the subset of fields that have column header tags that are common between the 2 files and only when the `name` matches. It'll also work no matter where the `name` column exists in each file.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a database operation on CSV data:

```
sqlite3 '' <<'EOD'
.mode csv
.separator |
.import "file 1" t1
.import file2 t2
update t1
    set
        email = t2.email,
        "country " = t2."country "
    from ( select * from t2 ) as t2
    where t1.name = t2.name;
.headers on
.output file1.new
select * from t1 order by rowid;
EOD
```

which writes `file1.new`:

```
name|gender|phone|email|city|"country "
abc|F|11111|zzzzzzzz|pune|USA
xyz|M|22222|wassrrrrtf|delhi|india
```

I assume values in the name column in `file2` are distinct, so there is a 1:1 name→country mapping. If this is not the case, one country will be picked randomly. (Likewise for email.)

Adjust the column name if you didn't intend the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`join`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=join&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html) with a little awk to tidy up

```bash
join --header -t '|' -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.4,1.6 -a 1 file1 file2 |
   awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$(NF-1) == "" {$(NF-1) = $NF} {NF--} 1'
```

```
name|gender|phone|email|city|country
abc|F|11111|ldiskmsjdh|pune|USA
xyz|M|22222|wassrrrrtf|delhi|india
```

Unfortunately with `join` you have to be explicit about the position of the join fields and the select fields

Comment: +1 for the awesome `awk` trick there. However I'd prefer if you were explicit about the fact that join must have the input sorted by the key column or it will fail. Also, `--header` is not universally available. You can calculate the join fields and the select fields automatically though. I didn't feel comfortable yoinking your key insight, so I put the filled-out (and Darwin-friendly) code [here](https://gist.github.com/amadanmath/1c488af92e3e50b8815efd50cc66560e) in case you want to edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

Program: `merge.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    FS  = "|"
    OFS = "|"
    FILE1_KEY_COL    = 1
    FILE1_COL_NAME   = 1
    FILE1_COL_GENDER = 2
    FILE1_COL_PHONE  = 3
    FILE1_COL_CITY   = 5
    FILE2_KEY_COL     = 2
    FILE2_COL_NAME    = 2
    FILE2_COL_EMAIL   = 3
    FILE2_COL_COUNTRY = 4
}
NR == FNR && FNR == 1 {
    # Ignore first line
    next
}
NR == FNR {
    FILE_2_NAME[$FILE2_KEY_COL]    = $FILE2_COL_NAME
    FILE_2_EMAIL[$FILE2_KEY_COL]   = $FILE2_COL_EMAIL
    FILE_2_COUNTRY[$FILE2_KEY_COL] = $FILE2_COL_COUNTRY
}
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
    print $0
    next
}
NR != FNR && FILE_2_NAME[$FILE1_KEY_COL] != $FILE1_KEY_COL {
    print $FILE1_KEY_COL > "/dev/stderr"
    next
}
NR != FNR {
    print $FILE1_COL_NAME,$FILE1_COL_GENDER,$FILE1_COL_PHONE,FILE_2_EMAIL[$FILE1_KEY_COL],$FILE1_COL_CITY,FILE_2_COUNTRY[$FILE1_KEY_COL]
}
```

Executed like that:

```bash
awk -f merge.awk file2 file1 >new_records 2>unknown_records
```

Warning: `file2` (the reference with new values) must be before the `file1`

## UPDATE

In order to use more and more fields. You could generate parts on awk script lines, like this :

Declarations:

```bash
$ cat file1 | head -1 | tr '|' "\n" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | awk '{printf("FILE_1_COL_%-20s = %d\n", $0, i+1); i++}'
FILE_1_COL_NAME                 = 1
FILE_1_COL_GENDER               = 2
FILE_1_COL_PHONE                = 3
FILE_1_COL_EMAIL                = 4
FILE_1_COL_CITY                 = 5
FILE_1_COL_COUNTRY              = 6

$ cat file2 | head -1 | tr '|' "\n" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | awk '{printf("FILE_2_COL_%-20s = %d\n", $0, i+1); i++}'
FILE_2_COL_SNO                  = 1
FILE_2_COL_NAME                 = 2
FILE_2_COL_EMAIL                = 3
FILE_2_COL_COUNTRY              = 4
```

File 2 memorization:

```bash
cat file2 | head -1 | tr '|' "\n" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | awk '{printf("FILE_2_%s[$FILE_2_KEY_COL] = $FILE_2_COL_%s\n", $0, $0); i++}'
FILE_2_SNO[$FILE_2_KEY_COL] = $FILE_2_COL_SNO
FILE_2_NAME[$FILE_2_KEY_COL] = $FILE_2_COL_NAME
FILE_2_EMAIL[$FILE_2_KEY_COL] = $FILE_2_COL_EMAIL
FILE_2_COUNTRY[$FILE_2_KEY_COL] = $FILE_2_COL_COUNTRY
```

Print:

```bash
$ cat file1 | head -1 | tr '|' "\n" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | awk 'BEGIN {printf("print ")} i>0 {printf(",")} {printf("$FILE_1_COL_%s", $0); i++} END {printf("\n")}'
print $FILE_1_COL_NAME,$FILE_1_COL_GENDER,$FILE_1_COL_PHONE,$FILE_1_COL_EMAIL,$FILE_1_COL_CITY,$FILE_1_COL_COUNTRY
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am looking for something generic as the actual file will have over 300 columns. Can you help with same?

Comment: I have updated 3 times my response

Comment: I tried the general one and it worked..!! Thank you so much..It is replacing the required columns as it’s supposed to. Thanks once again. If I could trouble you one more time, I wanted to know that if I wanted to print the rows whose keys don’t match as it is from file1..then how can I do that?

Comment: I have updated  my script to print on error flow unknown records

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awkward but general solution.

```
# patch_csv.awk

BEGIN {
  FS="|"
}

FNR==NR {
  if (FNR == 1) {
    nf1 = NF
    print
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      header1[i] = $i
      if ($i == "name") {
        key = i
      }
    }
  } else {
    data[$key] = $0
  }
}

FNR!=NR {
  if (FNR == 1) {
    for (j = 1; j <= NF; j++) {
      header2[j] = $j
      if ($j == "name") {
        key = j
      }
      for (i = 1; i <= nf1; i++) {
        if (header1[i] == header2[j]) {
          colmap[i] = j
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (data[$key]) {
    split(data[$key], record, FS)
    for (i = 1; i <= nf1; i++) {
      printf "%s%s", (colmap[i] ? $colmap[i] : record[i]), (i == nf1 ? "\n" : FS)
    }
  }
}
```

Run like this:

```
awk -f patch_csv.awk file1 file2
```

Output:

```
name|gender|phone|email|city|country
abc|F|11111|zzzzzzzz|pune|USA
```

Note that this is a very primitive handling of CSV format, as it does not support quoting or multiline values.

Of course, this would be much simpler in, say, Python or Ruby. Not to mention they also handle the full CSV specification correctly.

But if you are willing to hardcode column numbers, then this might be simpler:

```
head -1 file1.csv && \
join -t '|' -1 1 -2 2 \
  <(tail -n +2 file1.csv | sort -t '|' -k 1,1) \
  <(tail -n +2 file2.csv | sort -t '|' -k 2,2) | \
awk -v FS='|' \
  '{ print($1 FS $2 FS $3 FS ($8 ? $8 : $4) FS $5 FS ($9 ? $9 : $6)) }'
```

Print the header using `head -1`. Then use `join` to display the rows of the first file joined to the second file, using the first column of the first file (`-1 1`) and the second column of the second file (`-2 2`). For `join`, the files must be sorted; so first tear off the header (`tail -n +2`), then sort each file on the relevant column (`sort -k`). Both `join` and `sort` should use `|` as the separator (`-t '|'`). The `join` output contains columns from both files, so we need to merge them ourselves, and we can use `awk` to do so, e.g. by printing the 4th field if the 8th one is empty. Note that the row order is not preserved.

EDIT: If you have 300 fields... just use a proper programming language lol

EDIT2: Ruby version, because I have been challenged. Also, does outer join, since OP clarified:

```
require 'csv'

abort "Usage: #{__FILE__} <data_csv> <patch_csv> <key_field>" unless ARGV.length == 3
key = ARGV[2].to_sym
data_table = CSV.table(ARGV[0], col_sep: '|')
patch_table = CSV.table(ARGV[1], col_sep: '|')
common_fields = data_table.headers & patch_table.headers
patch_hash = patch_table.map { |row| [row[:name], row.to_h.slice(*common_fields) ] }.to_h
result_csv = CSV.generate(col_sep: "|", headers: true ) { |csv|
  csv << data_table.headers
  data_table.each { |row|
    csv << row.to_h.merge(patch_hash[row[key]] || {}) }
}
puts result_csv
```

Comment: I couldn’t find any change in the code.

Comment: Having used python and ruby, I'm not sure this would be any simpler in either of those than it is [in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78060884/1745001), GNU awk with `--csv` also handles the full CSV spec if that were necessary, and 300+ fields is trivial and efficient for awk to handle since it's designed specifically to manipulate text like this.

Comment: @user23482267 What do you mean, change in the code? What kind of change in the code were you expecting?

Comment: @EdMorton `gawk` is not guaranteed to be installed (and especially the 2023 `gawk`, at this time), and `--csv` option does not allow non-comma separators, so further processing is needed. `awkextlib` `gawk-csv` does allow it, but is even less likely to be installed. And looking at plain `awk`, I do believe Ruby's `CSV.table` and Python's `csv.DictReader` make the code more readable than shuffling column indices around (and also handle the bits of CSV that plain `awk` either can't or makes painful). I edited in a Ruby implementation for comparison. (Granted, Ruby might not be present either.)

Comment: @Amadan unfortunately I don't have ruby available on any of the systems I have access to now so I can't test the ruby solution you posted (thanks, by the way!), does it produce the expected output? Though obviously briefer, I personally don't find that simpler than my awk solution but I can see that maybe I would if I was more familiar with the constructs you used. You're right that `gawk --csv` doesn't support characters other than `|`, that would need to be modified if the OP needed full CSV parsing.

Comment: It'd actually be good if you posted the ruby script as a separate answer as others looking for a solution in future might want to adopt it and may not notice it at the end of this one.